# Omniture Report REST API call

Tags: adobe-analytics

Can anyone suggest me regarding Omniture REST API call in order to generate report (for example; I need to generate monthly report for top ten browsers by revenue and top ten browsers by operating system etc?

Comment: Thanks for your response. It really helped me a lot. but I have one more question which is that how could I generate report for Top ten browsers by operating systems?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**First, use the `Report.Queue` method to create the report request.**

Here is an example for last month:

```
{
    "reportDescription":{
        "reportSuiteID":"rsidhere",
        "date":"2015-10",
        "metrics":[
            {
                "id":"revenue"
            }
        ],
        "sortBy":"revenue",
        "elements":[
            {
                "id":"browser",
                "top":"10",
                "startingWith":"1"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

This should give you a response with the report request id, example:

```
{
    "reportID":123456789
}
```

**Then, use `Report.GetQueue` to check the status of the report.**

The only thing to send to this method is an empty `[]` array. The report queue is global to the whole company. It will return an array of objects that look something like this (example):

```
[
    {
        "reportID":"123456789",
        "type":"ranked",
        "queueTime":"2015-11-14 03:24:23",
        "status":"waiting",
        "priority":"0",
        "estimate":"0",
        "user":"user"
    }
    // , {..}
]
```

Since more than 1 object can be in the array (depends on if you have any other reports in the queue), you will have to loop through it and look for the `reportID` that matches.

The `status` property will show "waiting" or "running". It will never show "complete" or anything. If you do NOT find your `reportID` in the array, that means the report is complete and ready to retrieve.

**When the report is ready, use the `Report.Get` method to retrieve the report.**

You use the same returned value from the original `Report.Queue` to get the report:

```
{
    "reportID":123456789
}
```

*Note: The documentation says if you attempt to use `Report.Get` when the report is not ready to be retrieved, you will get an error message saying the report is not ready. So at face value, this sounds like a reasonable way to skip checking `Report.GetQueue`. However, in practice, I have found that depending on what type of report I request, how much data will be returned, etc. (I don't know exact formula), this is not true. Sometimes it will instead return a partial report!*

The returned report will look something like this (example):

- `data[n].name` shows the browser
- `data[n].counts[0]` shows the revenue

*response*

```
{
    "report":{
        "type":"ranked",
        "elements":[
            {
                "id":"browser",
                "name":"Browser"
            }
        ],
        "reportSuite":{
            "id":"rsidhere",
            "name":"some rsid"
        },
        "period":"October 2015",
        "metrics":[
            {
                "id":"revenue",
                "name":"Revenue",
                "type":"currency",
                "decimals":2,
                "latency":2696,
                "current":false
            }
        ],
        "data":[
            {
                "name":"Microsoft Internet Explorer 11",
                "url":"",
                "counts":[
                    "474127.13"
                ]
            },
            {
                "name":"Google Chrome 45.0",
                "url":"",
                "counts":[
                    "409498.61"
                ]
            },
            {
                "name":"Google Chrome 46.0",
                "url":"",
                "counts":[
                    "355380.86"
                ]
            },
            {
                "name":"Safari 9.0",
                "url":"",
                "counts":[
                    "275003.13"
                ]
            },
            {
                "name":"Mozilla Firefox 41.0",
                "url":"",
                "counts":[
                    "166427.91"
                ]
            },
            {
                "name":"Safari 8.0",
                "url":"",
                "counts":[
                    "125681.54"
                ]
            },
            {
                "name":"Safari 0.8.2",
                "url":"",
                "counts":[
                    "103866.64"
                ]
            },
            {
                "name":"::unspecified::",
                "url":"",
                "counts":[
                    "87761.87"
                ]
            },
            {
                "name":"Safari 8.0.8",
                "url":"",
                "counts":[
                    "79675.79"
                ]
            },
            {
                "name":"Safari 9.0.1",
                "url":"",
                "counts":[
                    "76977.82"
                ]
            }
        ],
        "totals":[
            "2823943.75"
        ],
        "version":"1.4.15.11"
    },
    "waitSeconds":"0.943",
    "runSeconds":"8.710"
}
```

*Note: You can use [Adobe API Explorer](https://marketing.adobe.com/developer/api-explorer) to try out the API methods and see responses and help build your scripts.*

Comment: any suggestion for doing this API call using java, sending the report.queue in JSON format in Java?

Comment: @Abdullah I'm not a Java expert but a quick google search shows there are a ton of Java libraries out there for making JSON requests. I mean that's essentially all it is.

Answer (score -1):

I created a python module that works as an high level API for Adobe Analytics. 
You can check it out here : [http://www.datanalyst.info/python/adobe-api/adobe-analytics-api-introduction/](http://www.datanalyst.info/python/adobe-api/adobe-analytics-api-introduction/?camp=sm~stackoverflow~adobe-question)

It will retrieved you the report you want and save it as csv file.

Comment: Hi Pitchkrak -- I'd ask you to make your answer self-contained (i.e. all the relevant bits are written here) rather than just link to an external website. By all means, leave the link, but post appropriate code snippet here :-)